# Excel VBA error when calling MS Project Task's Unique ID

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

In an Excel worksheet, I am iterating through tasks in a MS Project file with VBA.

I've found that my code works perfectly until I encounter a MS Project task that does not have a name but the error is confusing me. When I delete these unnamed tasks, the error goes away.

I tried adding an if statement: `If prj.Tasks(i).UniqueID Is Nothing Then` to catch this error but I get a `Type mismatch` error.

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim TaskID As Long
Dim ExcelRow As Integer
For i = 1 To prj.Tasks.Count
    TaskID = prj.Tasks(i).UniqueID  'This line is highlighted when I debug
    ExcelRow = GetRowByUniqueID(TaskID)
    Debug.Print ExcelRow
```

My error is Object variable not set (Error 91). I am confused by this because I was under the impression that all Tasks have a unique ID. When I open my .mpp file in Microsoft Project, I can see that the tasks have no name but have a unique ID in the Unique ID column.

Edit: I just realized it is not an issue with `prj.Tasks(i).UniqueID` but rather an issue with `prj.Tasks(i)`. How is it possible that this variable is not set when `i` is within the range of the number of Tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I just figured it out.
Somehow, when I iterate through all the Tasks, some of them are `Nothing`. I don't really understand why but at the very least, I was able to catch this with an if statement:

```vb
If prj.Tasks(i) Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "This is nothing."

Else
    TaskID = prj.Tasks(i).UniqueID
    ExcelRow = GetRowByUniqueID(TaskID)
    Debug.Print ExcelRow
```

Now, my code does not break at all.

Comment: Since `Tasks` is an object collection, would declaring a local `currentTask` variable and then iterating with `For Each currentTask In prj.Tasks` work? (it would probably be more efficient anyway, since object collections *want* to be iterated with `For Each`).. it's very odd that `Tasks` contains `Nothing` items.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for your suggestion. I tested that out and I'm getting the same error as I had before. After I added the if statement again, the code no longer breaks. So even with the `For Each currentTask in prj.Tasks`, some `currentTask`s are still Nothing ...

Comment: Interesting. Looks like the Project API is somewhat broken - I'm not familiar with it at all, but that's definitely surprising behavior. Indeed, that null-check seems to be your only hope.

Comment: @vivianyoung testing for nothing is the standard way to handle this when looping through tasks. As @MathieuGuindon mentioned, using a `for...each` loop also works and is often preferable due to not having to first know how many tasks there are (and it looks cleaner).

Comment: @RachelHettinger [and it's dramatically more efficient for iterating object collections](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/)

Comment: @RachelHettinger Got it! Thank you both for your help! :)